# how to get json data object response in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I want to get the data in the format crave-reply, crave-reply like this . I want to display crave with all its replyes one by one. In view i am getting the crave with its all reply. But while passing it to the response i am not getting the proper data.

views.py

```
def get_post_android_crave(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        craves =list(CraveData.objects.all())
        te = FacebookUser.objects.get(person=request.user)
        img = te.image
        user_name=te.first_name+te.middle_name+te.last_name
        for crave in craves:
            reply= list(Comment.objects.filter(crave=crave))
            for reply_each in reply:
                response1 = {
                            'Crave': craves,
                            'reply': reply_each,}
                response2 = serializers.serialize('json',response1)
                response=json.dumps(response2 )
                print response        
                return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
```

Getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                url: domain+"/crave/getpostandroidcrave/",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (response) 
                {       
                        data= JSON.stringify(response)
                        alert(data);


                },
                error: function () 
                {
                    alert('some error');
                }
            });
```

Here i am getting error. Because its getting into the ajax error function.
Can anyone tell me how to get the data crave after reply, crave after reply.

Example:- crave1
               Reply11
               Reply12
          crave2
               Reply21
               Reply22
like this.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack-trace for the error? There isn't enough information here to help you

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't get all the data, because "return"  located in wrong place.

2) As for exception. Instead of:

```
response1 = {
    'Crave': craves,
    'reply': reply_each,}
response2 = serializers.serialize('json',response1)
```

for example try this

```
import json
response1 = {
    'Crave': json.loads(serializers.serialize('json',craves)),
    'reply': json.loads(serializers.serialize('json',reply_each)),
}
response2 = serializers.serialize('json',response1)
```